# Saving additional node fields programmatically

Tags: 7

I have the following content type called `stars` with the following fields:

```
Title
Body
Distance (this is an added text field)
```

Here's what I have to save the node, but how do I add the distance field?

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = "stars";
$node->status = 0;
$node->uid = $user->uid;
$node->title = 'This is the title';
$node->sticky = 0;
$node->language = 'en';

// Let's add standard body field
$node->body['und'][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html';
$node->body['und'][0]['value'] = 'Body info';

$node->revision = 0;

node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to set the value for the *Distance* field just like you have already for the *Body* field. Lets assume that the name of your *Distance* field is `field_star_distance`. (To find the name of your field, check if you have the `Field UI` module enabled and head over to the *Manage fields* page for your content type)

```
// Your code
$node->{'field_star_distance'}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 100;
// Your code
```

The general skeleton for setting the value for a field of an entity is:

```
$entity->{$field_name}[$language][$delta][$field_property] = $value
```

To understand the different field properties for a given field (like `value` in our example here), you need to look up its schema ([see](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_schema/7) `hook_field_schema()` and [see](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!text!text.install/function/text_field_schema/7) `text_field_schema()`)

To see if `$delta` can be  `> 1`, you need to check the cardinality of the field instance.

Answer (score -1):

$node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']= $name;

where 'field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] 'is the name of the extra added node field.you can get this name by inspect property of browser.