# Saving body as HTML in custom content types

Tags: forms

I have a custom content type that I want to save data to,

the content type has custom fields and I used a secondary form that supplies the from data to be stored, when the user sees the view, the Body of the content type is actually the fields put together in a nice styled format like so:

User fills in form->node gets saved as content type->user is sent to new page.

In the new page only the body is displayed, but the problem I have is that when I save the content it gets saved as plain text so none of the html is rendered, this is the code that saves the content type ( i have left out the custom content types as they are saved how I want them to be saved:

```
$node = new stdClass();
    $node->type = 'client_account';
    $node->title = $form_state['values']['groupName'];
    $node->uid = $user->uid;
    $node->name = $user->name;
    $node->comment = 0;
    $node->promote = 0;
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    $node->is_new = True;
    $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#format'] = 'full_html';
    $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = ' html table goes here with filed values inserted';
```

I havew a feeling that I am using the #format = 'full_html' incorrectly and would appreciate some advice on the matter.

Jim

Comment: Please, try $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format'] = 'full_html'; (remove '#') http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53981/saving-additional-node-fields-programmatically

Comment: I highly recommend saving user input as is and making it HTML on output. That's how Drupal is doing it by default, and coding against framework is hard - and hardly ever really needed.

Comment: Thanks, ive realised adding the format = full_html line stops the form from saving the body content, so i am a bit stumped on this one...